# Office UI Fabric React : Dropdown Component

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How to change the CSS of label for Dropdown? Markup is as below:

```
<Dropdown
      placeHolder="Select Department"
      label="Department:"
      id="Basicdrop1"
      ariaLabel="Department"
      options={[

        { key: 'A', text: 'Option a' },
        { key: 'B', text: 'Option b' },
        { key: 'C', text: 'Option c'},
        { key: 'D', text: 'Option d' },
        { key: 'E', text: 'Option e' },
      ]}
      onFocus={() =>console.log('onFocus called')}
      onBlur={() =>console.log('onBlur called')}
      componentRef={this._basicDropdown}
    />
```

I want to make "Department" label bold.

Answer (score 3):

You can style the label by using the `styles` prop on `<Dropdown/>`. Here is a code sample which renders the label as bold:

```
<Fabric.Dropdown
  placeHolder="Select Department"
  label="Department:"
  id="Basicdrop1"
  ariaLabel="Department"
  options={[

    { key: 'A', text: 'Option a' },
    { key: 'B', text: 'Option b' },
    { key: 'C', text: 'Option c'},
    { key: 'D', text: 'Option d' },
    { key: 'E', text: 'Option e' },
  ]}
  onFocus={() =>console.log('onFocus called')}
  onBlur={() =>console.log('onBlur called')}
  componentRef={this._basicDropdown}
  styles={{ label: { fontWeight: 'bold' }}}
/>
```

**References**

- https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Component-Styling#styles-prop
- https://codepen.io/kevintcoughlin/pen/gBXvRZ?editors=1010